# How to debug my PHP CRUD system?

Tags: php, mysql

I am a beginner to a PHP and currently work on simple CRUD system about list of internship's students on localhost. The system is about admin key in data into a form before insert into phpmyadmin database, the problem is the data from the database cannot be fetch to be displayed into list of table in localhost webpage.

I have these problems:

1. The mysql extension is deprecated.
2. Warning: Division by zero.
3. Couldn't execute query

Below is my code for `detailintern.php` and three errors which are mentioned above.

```
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

$page = $_GET['page'];
// get the requested page
$limit = $_GET['rows'];
// get how many rows we want to have into the grid
$sidx = $_GET['sidx'];
// get index row - i.e. user click to sort
$sord = $_GET['sord']; 
// get the direction if(!$sidx)
$sidx =1;

$Scol=$_GET['Scol'];
$Stext=$_GET['Stext'];

// connect to the database
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","admin") or die("Connection Error: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("LI",$db) or die("Error conecting to db.");

    if(isset($_GET['Scol']) && $Stext!='')
    {
        $fCountSQL="SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM  biodata b, uni u WHERE b.University=u.shortname and b.{$Scol} LIKE '%{$Stext}%'";
    }
    else
    {
        $fCountSQL="SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM biodata b, uni u WHERE b.University=u.shortname";
    }

$result = mysql_query($fCountSQL);

//echo "$result";

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

//echo "$row";

$count = $row['count'];
    if( $count > 0 ) 
    {
        $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit);
    } 
    else 
    {
        $total_pages = 0;
    }
    if ($page > $total_pages) 
        $page=$total_pages;
    $start = $limit*$page - $limit; // do not put $limit*($page - 1)

    $responce = new stdClass();
    $responce->page = $page;
    $responce->total = $total_pages;
    $responce->records = $count;
    $i=0;

    if($start<0)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        if(isset($_GET["Scol"]) && $Stext!="")
        {
            $SQL="SELECT b.IC, b.Name, b.Telephone, b.Gender, b.Email, u.name, u.shortname, b.Age, b.Address , b.DOB
            FROM biodata b, uni u 
            WHERE b.University=u.shortname  and b.{$Scol} LIKE '%{$Stext}%' ORDER BY $sidx $sord LIMIT $start , $limit";
        }
        else
        {
            $SQL = "SELECT b.IC, b.Name, b.Telephone, b.Gender, b.Email, u.name, u.shortname, b.Age, b.Address , b.DOB
            FROM biodata b, uni u WHERE b.University=u.shortname 
            ORDER BY $sidx $sord LIMIT $start , $limit";
        }
        $result = mysql_query( $SQL ) or die("Couldn t execute query.".mysql_error());
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
        {
            $responce->rows[$i]['id']=$row[IC];
            $responce->rows[$i]['cell']=array($row[IC],$row[Name],$row[Telephone],$row[Gender],$row[Email],$row[name],$row[shortname],$row[Age],$row[Address], $row[DOB]);
            $i++;
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($responce);
?>
```

Comment: These are 3 different questions. ask them seperatley.

Comment: No dont ask them, just google each error. They are very common errors and are all over if you simply google them.

Comment: I already done with google and so on, to be more specific i am asking them, by the way thanks.

Comment: Watch out for SQL injection vulnerabilities in this code.

Comment: For your `Couldn't execute query`, what is the error you get from `mysql_error()`?

Comment: There are so many problems with your code, your 3 questions being answered wouldn't really get you anywhere.

Comment: I got this 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3'

Comment: ok, all of you are right, but we were all beginners some day - let's give him a chance to improve his skills and learn them :)

Answer (score 2):

The MySQL extension is deprecated since PHP 5.5.0 and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (note the **i** at the end) or [PHP PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) should be used instead. Also, you are probably getting the division by zero warning because $count or $limit is returning 0.

Answer (score 0):

I have on some old sites still old mysql and is working, but I suggest you as @Matu to start using Mysqli or PDO.

For other 2 errors: check if you query is ok and not empty as I saw you did

```
    if(isset($_GET['Scol']) && $Stext!='')
        {
            $fCountSQL="SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM  biodata b, uni u WHERE b.University=u.shortname and b.{$Scol} LIKE '%{$Stext}%'";
        }
        else
        {
            $fCountSQL="SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM biodata b, uni u WHERE b.University=u.shortname";
        }

    $result = mysql_query($fCountSQL);

Better would be to setup $fCountSql variable before if statements:

$fCountSQL = '';
if(isset($_GET['Scol']) && $Stext!='')
    {
        $fCountSQL="SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM  biodata b, uni u WHERE b.University=u.shortname and b.{$Scol} LIKE '%{$Stext}%'";
    }
    else
    {
        $fCountSQL="SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM biodata b, uni u WHERE b.University=u.shortname";
    }

if(!empty($fCountSQL)){
$result = mysql_query($fCountSQL);
//check if you get result, or if num_rows > 0, ..., make sure is not empty or 0, or false,
if(!$result){
return false;
}

... proceed with processing results ...
}
```

For simple **debugging**, you can use something like that:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');

ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```